# Send path route via ajax call (using fleupload jquery plugin)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload

What I am trying to accomplish is the following.  I want to be able to send a file path (such as "~/MyFolder/MySubFolder") through Ajax to a MVC 4 controller.  The problem I'm facing is that, I'm using the fileupload jquery plugin and this does not give me direct control over what I send over to the server (meaning, it sends the file with a couple of attributes but I can't add extra attributes to it).

I was trying to send the path as an html attribute to the ajax call:

```
url: "/api/upload" + path
```

but for obvious reasons this doesn't work.  Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am right you are using this plugin [BluImp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data)

[1](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data): https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload for file upload and sending additional data is supported is available in this try like this :

```
<form id="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="example1" value="test">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Example: <input type="text" name="example2"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

By default, the plugin calls jQuery's serializeArray method on the upload form to gather additional form data for all input fields (including hidden fields).
The value of these form fields will be sent to the server along with the selected files.

Note:
If you set the formData option, these fields won't be sent to the server, since the formData object will override them.
You can however create a formData object of the form fields manually using jQuery's serializeArray method method:

For more info : [Plugin wiki](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data)

Comment: This is a great way to start. So, I have added a data.formData = {filepath: path}; to the submit option of the plugin.  How would I access that server side? (because it is not part of the file itself) Thanks for your help

Comment: Try getting $filepath = $_POST['filepath']; If you are at PHP.

Comment: I'm actually using MVC 4...I really don't know anything about PHP :/

Comment: Using something like     string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MyVariable"]; 
works perfectly!! Thanks for all your help man :)